# Kobuki Left Bumper stuck

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base, kobuki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My Kobuki left bumper has somehow gotten stuck, I could probably live with this, but it messes up the auto_docking node, which reports **feedback: [dockdrive: bumped]:** and my robot just backs up.

I've verified the behavior by running the following commands in order.

- roscore
- rostopic echo /mobile_base/events/bumper
- roslaunch kobuki_node minimal.launch --screen

As soon as the kobuki_node comes up the echo report the following below.  Also, the right and center bumper work as expected.

```
bumper: 0
state: 1
```

Pressing the left bumper has no effect on the echo command above.  Ie. the Kobuki think the left bumper is always pressed.  So I have two options:

**Option 1:**  Find some documentation on how to take the bumper off and see why it's stuck.

**Option 2:** Get the auto_docking node to work despite the left bumper being stuck.**

Any ideas?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228933/kobuki-left-bumper-stuck/) by [jseal](https://answers.ros.org/users/20018/jseal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 258 on 2016-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you take a flat head screw drive and slide it into the opening on the side of the bumper, you can then pry up enough to see a white contact switch with a flashlight (be very carefully).  A second screw driver can then be used to unfree the stuck bumper.

With the bumper not stuck the auto dock routine works perfect.

---

Originally posted by [jseal](https://answers.ros.org/users/20018/jseal/) with karma: 258 on 2016-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0